# Highcharts, use UTC on X axis, but not on Y axis

Tags: date, datetime, highcharts

I need to display a chart that shows local time on X axis and latency on Y axis (in format HH:MM:SS).

I can set UTC globally:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: true
    }
});
```

If I set it to true, my Y axis is correct, but my X axis reports wrong datetime (compared to local time).

If I set it to false, my Y axis starts from 1 instead of 0 (I am in UTC+1 timezone), but my X axis reports correct datetime.

How to have UTC disabled on X axis (to show local time) and enabled on Y axis (to show latency in HH:MM:SS) starting from 00:00:00 and not 01:00:00 ?

EDIT:

Added this JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7bnseg8m

UTC is false. X axis in local time. Y axis is in milliseconds.

How can I format Y axis to be in "HH:MM". I've looked into below link, but it does not seem possible. http://highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatt‌​ing

Comment: Seems like its an issue of data calculation, i.e. one is UTC based, the other local. Suggest you include a jsFiddle or code snippet of the chart options and X and Y value equations.

Comment: As it is a global setting, this can't be done in this way. You would either have to figure out time zone and adjust your data accordingly, or go with a non `datetime` format - I would personally choose to plot it as either seconds or minutes instead, which makes it easier both from a chart config perspective, and a numeric comparison perspective, FWIW.

Comment: Added this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7bnseg8m/

UTC is false. X axis in local time. Y axis is in milliseconds. How can I format Y axis to be in "HH:MM". I've looked into below link, but it does not seem possible.

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

Comment: Set format  for yAxis as you do in xAxis.labels - http://jsfiddle.net/7bnseg8m/1/

Comment: morgan, the format you specified is for datetime axis - which is also the reason it is showing 00:00. If i provide the value in milliseconds, then how can I format that to HH:MM ?